# Validate complex XML in Powershell

Tags: xml, validation, powershell

I am working on a script that reads data from XML to determine a workflow, and that XML has become quiet complex; all of these variations on  are valid, the ID attribute is optional, there are some other optional attributes for the main node, and I am looking at the possibility of different optional attributes and nodes as well.

```
<ManageINI id="TASK ID">
  <Target>PATH TO INI</Target>
  <DeleteKey>
    <Section>SECTION NAME</Section>
    <Name>KEY NAME</Name>
  </DeleteKey>
</ManageINI>
<ManageINI id="TASK ID">
  <Target>PATH TO INI</Target>
  <ReviseKey>
    <Section>SECTION NAME</Section>
    <Name>KEY NAME</Name>
    <Value>VALUE</Value>
  </ReviseKey>
</ManageINI>
<ManageINI id="TASK ID">
  <Target>PATH TO INI</Target>
  <ReviseKey>
    <Source>PATH TO INI</Source>
    <Section>SECTION NAME</Section>
    <Name>KEY NAME</Name>
  </ReviseKey>
</ManageINI>
<ManageINI id="TASK ID">
  <Target>PATH TO INI</Target>
  <ReplaceString>
    <Replace>STRING 1</Replace>
    <With>STRING 2</With>
  </ReplaceString>
</ManageINI>
```

And the XML is currently human edited, and may need to remain that way for a while. Also, the "user" in this case is potentially a somewhat non-technical person. Very smart people, but more likely to be an Architect or Structural Engineer thrust into an Irish role that someone with an IT background.
What I would like to do is validate the XML and provide meaningful logged feedback on any issues. If someone misspells a node name, I want to flag that. If someone uses an optional attribute on a node that doesn't support it, I want to flag that. If someone uses an incorrect value in an attribute, I want to flag that. And, I have 25 other Nodes nearly as complex as , but also totally different.
I am thinking there are potentially three ways to approach this, and I am unsure of which path to go down.

1: Schema based validation. It seems to me that the XML I have is so complex that schema based validation just doesn't work. But perhaps I am not understanding the approach very well. Also, could I create the schema as a here string in the function, so as to keep things self contained and modular? Or would I have to use an XSL file that then needs to be managed separately from the code that uses the validated XML?

2: "Pattern" matching. Each "task" node is passed to the appropriate function as an `[Xml.XmlElement]`. If I also created an `[Xml.XmlElement]` in the function, of all valid examples of proper use, I could write some code that would compare the passed Node with the options.

3: I could just write code that looks at the XML and logs issues. This seems like potentially the most work, and least elegant, but also the most flexible. It's also the kind of approach I have used before only to find out later there was a MUCH better way. ;)

This is a somewhat abstract question I know, but hopefully someone has crossed this bridge before and can point me in the right direction before I spend a bunch of time (probably on option 3) only to find I chose the wrong path.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but can you just to a `Get-Content | Convertfrom-Xml` and then do whatever validation you need to on each property of the resultant object?

Comment: That's basically my third option. I can read in the XML, then loop through all the attributes looking for invalid ones, loop through all the nodes looking for invalid ones, etc. But so often I go that route and then discover there is a better way. Like, if I could provide some XML of all valid variations, and some cmdlet could validate in a single line of code, that would be slick.

Comment: Ahh ok.  Yea I can't think of an easy way to do that with a few commands (although there may be an XML class feature I'm not aware of). On the flip side if anyone but you will ever need to maintain this just pulling it in and evaluating everything with if statements is going to be the easiest for another PowerShell dev to figure out and support later. Could also look into using pester to do all your tests declaratively rather than with a bunch of boolean, would give a nice output showing where the problem is that way to

Comment: Well, given my audience I think I might need to go the long way on the logs, but I didn't know about Pester! So now I know I should just implement the validation myself, but I should test my implantation with Pester. Woot.